# Go: Why does os.Getwd() sometimes fail with EOF

Tags: go

```
package main
import "os"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    _, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

This sometimes prints an error of EOF. Does anyone know why? There's usually some os.Chdir happening before, but that doesn't error out.

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"

go version go1.0.3
```

Comment: Please add Go version/OS platform/CPU arch info and - if possible - a minimal program to reproduce.

Comment: Just a guess since i've never had this happen to me. But is it possible that the chdir moved to a directory with wonky permissions so an attempt to get the current directory fails as unreadable?

Comment: Can you repeat the test? This time instead of printing the error normally, use `fmt.Printf("%v | %T | %#v\n", err, err, err)`.

Comment: `os.Getwd()` returns `string, error` so example doesn't compile: http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd

Comment: My guess is that it is a bug in the rather hideous getwd code: http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/getwd.go From my grepping OSX doesn't implement getwd as a syscall so it uses the fallback implementation above. I don't have a mac otherwise I'd have a go at debugging it! The only place the EOF can be returned is from `fd.Readdirnames(100)` which probably means that the current directory has been deleted or something else whacky going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `os.Getwd` that causes it to return EOF as error when the working directory no longer exists, on platforms that don't support the `getwd` syscall. Here is a repeatable test case on OS X.

```
package main
import "os"
import "fmt"

const DIR = "/tmp/somedir"

func main() {
    os.Remove(DIR)
    if err := os.Mkdir(DIR, 0755); err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      return
    }
    if err := os.Chdir(DIR); err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      return
    }
    if err := os.Remove(DIR); err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      return
    }
    wd, err := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
    fmt.Println("wd:", wd)
}
```

Output:

```
err: EOF
wd:
```